# bestappr function gives incorrect answer in pari/gp

Tags: pari-gp

`bestappr(sqrt(13),30)` gives `18/5` for any precision I tried, but a closer approximation is `101/28`. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Is seems to be PARI/GP's implementation drawback. Please, write to the PARI/GP developers mailing list: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/lists-index.html.

Comment: @PiotrSemenov I got it, I will try to write my own function. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For PARI/GP,

> By definition, a/b is the best rational approximation to x if |b x - a| < |vx  - u| for all integers (u,v) with 0 < v <= B.
>   (see `??bestappr`).

So in this case

|5x - 18| < |28x  - 101|

and so gp considers 18/5 the better approximation. The next approximation it considers better is 119/33 followed by 137/38.